# Código para checar se o GPS está ativo

Tags: android, gps

Bom dia,
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que checar vulnerabilidades no Android e gostaria de saber se alguém sabe de uma aplicação com o código aberto ou saiba do código que verifica se o GPS está ativo ou checar todos os aplicativos do dispositivo e avisar se estão usando o seu GPS.

obrigado

Answer (score 7):

Para saber se o GPS está ligado use este código:

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
bool isOn = manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Julgo que não há forma de saber quais as aplicações que, no momento, estão a utilizar o GPS.
É possível, no entanto, saber quais aplicações têm permissão para utilizá-lo:

```
PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager(); 
List<PackageInfo> appInstaladas = p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
```

Este código preenche a lista `appInstaladas` com informação sobre as aplicações instaladas, incluindo suas permissões.

Para obter a lista de permissões use, para cada um dos itens de `appInstaladas`:

```
//Retorna permissões declaradas em <uses-permission> 
String[] requestedPermissions = appInstaladas.get(index).requestedPermissions();

//Retorna permissões declaradas em <permission>
PermissionInfo[] permissions = appInstaldas.get(index).permissions();
```

**Fontes:**
[PackageInfo.requestedPermissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissions)
[PackageInfo.permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#permissions)
[SO.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3280756/2556111)

Comment: Muito obrigado Ramaral vou testar...abs

Answer (score 1):

Faz assim:

```
LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Verifica se o GPS está ativo
boolean enabled = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

// Caso não esteja ativo abre um novo diálogo com as configurações para
// realizar se ativamento
if (!enabled) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Você pode criar um metodo com um dialog para que o cliente possa escolher se ativa ou não o GPS. Mas dê uma lida no que o [Ramaral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2541/ramaral) falou.